# How do I make my images disappear when clicked using the code I have?

Tags: javascript, onclick, visibility, eventhandler

I'm overlaying images on top of each other and want to make it so when you click each one it disappears, revealing the image underneath.
This is what I have in the script tag:

```
function attach_eventhandler(d){
    d.onclick = function(){
        this.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
var myArray = document.getElementsByTagName("heart");
for(var d of myArray){
  attach_eventhandler(d);
}
```

And these are the two images I have right now. I want "heart" to disappear, then "pig".

```
<img id="pig"src="pig.jpg" alt= height="700 px" width="500 px">

<img id="heart"src="heart.jpg" alt= height="700 px" width="500 px">
```

Comment: Add an OnClick on those tags ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is, your images don't seem to overlay, unless you are applying css. To make them overlay you should use position:absolute. Like this:

```
<div>
    <img id="pig"src="pig.jpg" alt= height="700 px" width="500 px" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0">
    <img id="heart"src="heart.jpg" alt= height="700 px" width="500 px" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0">
</div>
```

Also, you want to call getElementsByTagName() with "img" instead of "heart", like this:

```
var myArray = document.getElementsByTagName("img");``
```

This is the complete page:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    
    <img id="pig"src="pig.jpg" alt= height="700 px" width="500 px" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0">
<img id="heart"src="heart.jpg" alt= height="700 px" width="500 px" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0">  
</div>  
<script>
function attach_eventhandler(d){
    d.onclick = function(){
        this.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
var myArray = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for(var d of myArray){
  attach_eventhandler(d);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**: Oh and, actually, maybe you're doing it, but you should run the script using the DOMContentLoaded event, like this:

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var myArray = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
        for(var d of myArray){
          attach_eventhandler(d);
        }
    });
    function attach_eventhandler(d){
        d.onclick = function(){
            this.style.visibility = "hidden";
        };
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say I'm also using css to make them overlay

Comment: Oh, ok, then the only problem with your code is this: getElementsByTagName("heart"). There's no "heart" tag, you want to search all the "img" tags. :)

Comment: @Ruby If you think this answer is correct, please mark it so the question if set as answered. :)

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: It's explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers :)

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to target 'heart' by id, since it does have an id

```js
const heart = document.getElementById("heart");
heart.addEventListener("click", () => {
  heart.style.visibility = "hidden";
})
```

```html
<img id="pig" src="pig.jpg" alt="pig" height="700 px" width="500 px">

<img id="heart" src="heart.jpg" alt="heart" height="700 px" width="500 px">
```

You can test this code by running it and clicking on "heart"